# pip won't install anything "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement..."

Tags: python, pip

I am struggling installing anything with pip. Everything I try to install gives me this error:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement (package I am trying to install) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for (package I am trying to install)

I have updated pip to the latest version.
Thanks for your help.

edit: Here is my pip and python versions:
[click here for versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHwIL.png)

Comment: Do you have python 2 or 3 installed ? Can you run `pip --version` and `pip3 --version`

Comment: pip install winsound

Answer (score 0):

It's part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html), no need to install. Try `python -c "import winsound"`.